# Get Image from Drawbale of Project in Android?

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying get the Drawable image from my java class using this link of code in my project..

```
private Drawable imgCloseButton = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_up_float);
```

But it is only showing the list of image of system not form my Drawable folder....

I also used this code to solve it ...

```
 String uri = "@drawable/app_icon";

int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null,
            "com.esysolutions.dilosys.v2.utility");

private Drawable imgCloseButton = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
```

But no Luck with this...  need help to get image from my project drawable ....

Comment: Are you working in right `context`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you `import android.R` instead of `your.package.R`?

if so then change it to `import your.package.R`

Answer (score 0):

Try

As you stated **showing the list of image of system** it seems like that you are `not building your project`

To build there are two ways **1st** Build Automatically **2nd** Build Manually

**1.** Go to **file menu** click **project** then **tick the Build Automatically** if its not ticked

**2.** Go to **file menu** click **project** then **click Build Project** or **right click on project** from package explorer and **click on build project**

**Note**  `2nd way is only possible if you are not using 1st one (Build Automatically )`

if still not working then again open **project** then **clean the project**

You should also verify `import of R` it should be `import yourackageName.R` instead of `import android.R`

Answer (score 0):

R.drawable will work only after creation of R.java file in Gen folder. There you can check the name of the drawables also, which are present in your drawable folder. So build and check, it will take drawable folder image.